# Hide TextView when SearchView is open

Tags: java, android, android-layout, searchview, androidx

I am using TextView on top of SearchView as a heading. The other option is customising the search query hint by changing the font, color, text size and centering. [This seems like a simpler method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E95KN.png)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbackground"
            android:closeIcon="@drawable/search_x_button"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:paddingStart="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="11dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="11dp"
            android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_ssearch"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/manrope_semibold"
            android:text="@string/search"
            android:textColor="@color/font_title"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

How can I set the textview to hide once the searchview is in focus, aka user taps on it and the blinking cursor appears?

Edit: fixed by doing this

```
searchHint = view.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
```

and then

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            if (query.equals("")) {
                searchHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                searchHint.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this:

Whenever you click on the TextView, change its visibility to GONE, and add the focus to the SearchView.

```
SearchView mSearchView = findViewById(R.id.searchview);
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView13)

textView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
     textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     mSearchView.setSearchFocused(true);
  });
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to hide the Hint text (@+id/textView13) when user click on SearchView(@+id/searchview).
If so, seem that you can add below codes(you can check if can meet your requirement)

```
    searchview.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            textView13.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            textView13.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```